# Obtener elemento generado por un SELECT clonado dinámico

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5

estoy batallando con este problemilla que no logro resolver.

Lo que hace el código es, al dar click en el botón "#add_Area", se genera un clon del DIV #form-inputs-row con todos sus hijos, y se agregar justo antes del contenedor del botón "#add_area".

El SELECT "#der_area" lo cargo mediante una consulta PHP que creo que no es necesario detallar.

Luego, cuando se seleccione alguna opción del SELECT "#add_area" automáticamente se carguen los datos correspondientes, en el SELECT "#responsable". Para esto realizo una consulta AJAX.

Todo esta funcionalidad del SELECT dinámico se replica en cada clon generado. Cabe señalar que para esto tuve inconvenientes, pero agreando el evento "DOMContentLoaded", pude solucionarlo, pero no se si sea la opción mas óptima.

El problema es, cuándo deseo obtener por consola el SELECT "#responsable" clonado con los datos cargados, luego de seleccionar alguna opción del SELECT "#der_area" clonado, a veces obtengo el SELECT "#responsable" con los datos correctos, y a veces solo el SELECT "#responsable" vacío.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

```js
function asignarEventoResponsables(select) {
        select.addEventListener("change", function() {
            const valor = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
            let selectResp = select.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector("#responsable");
            selectResp.innerHTML = "";

            const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST", "actions/consulta.php", true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajax.send("nombre_area=" + valor);
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                    let json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                    json.forEach(function(item) {
                        let option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.value = item.nombre + " " + item.apellido;
                        option.text = item.nombre + " " + item.apellido;
                        selectResp.appendChild(option);
                    });
                    selectResp.removeAttribute("disabled");
                    document.getElementById("der_observ").removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
            };
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const selectPrincipal = document.getElementById("der_area");
        asignarEventoResponsables(selectPrincipal);
    });

    document.getElementById("add-area").onclick = function() {
        let add_area = document.querySelector("#derivar-modal-contenedor form #form-inputs .add-area");
        let area = document.querySelector("#derivar-modal-contenedor form #form-inputs #form-inputs-row:first-child");
        let clone_area = area.cloneNode(true);

        let selectPrincipalClonado = clone_area.querySelector("#der_area");
        selectPrincipalClonado.removeAttribute("name");  

        let cloneResponsable = clone_area.querySelector("#responsable");
        cloneResponsable.removeAttribute("name");
        cloneResponsable.setAttribute("disabled", true);
        cloneResponsable.innerHTML = "";        

        document.querySelector("#derivar-modal-contenedor form #form-inputs").insertBefore(clone_area, add_area);

        asignarEventoResponsables(selectPrincipalClonado);

        selectPrincipalClonado.addEventListener("change", function() {
            let cloneResponsableActualizado = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector("#responsable");
            console.log(cloneResponsableActualizado);
        });
    };
```

```html
<div id="derivar-modal-contenedor">       
    <form id="form-derivar" action="javascript:void(0)" method="">
        <div id="form-inputs">
            <div id="form-inputs-row">
                <div>
                    <label for="der_area">Área / Unidad / Otros</label>
                    <select id="der_area" name="der_area">
                        <option selected disabled>---Seleccione---</option>
                        <option value="Valor obtenido con PHP 1">Valor obtenido con PHP 1</option>
                        <option value="Valor obtenido con PHP 2">Valor obtenido con PHP 2</option>
                        <option value="Valor obtenido con PHP 3">Valor obtenido con PHP 3</option>                         
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="responsable">Responsable</label>
                    <select id="responsable" name="responsable" disabled></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="form-inputs-row" class="add-area">
                <button id="add-area">Agregar Área / Unidad / Otros</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>       
</div>
```

En la consola, la mayoría de veces me devuelve el SELECT #responsable con los valores correctos, pero otras veces, me devuelve el SELECT vacío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El atributo `id` debe ser unico

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. ¿Cuál de todos?

Comment: **Todos** no deben tener los mismos `id`...

Comment: Cuando clonas, los estas haciendo con el `ìd` incluido, debes cambiarlo